# UIImageView/UIScrollView forcing a fixed aspect ratio to fit the screen

Tags: ipad, ios, uiscrollview, iphone

I am making a simple app for the iPad that consists of a giant image that you can zoom-in/out on and navigate.

This image is placed inside a `UIImageView`, which is then placed inside a `UIScrollView`.

The navigation and zooming work 100% fine; however, the image is loaded at a fixed aspect-ratio to fit the screen, and will never change (even when zooming-in).

I have a feeling that Interface Builder is setting some property that I'm not aware of, but I've tried everything that I can think of to fix this.

**The Problem:**

When the app initially loads, the contents inside the `UIScrollView` is automatically re-sized to exactly fit the iPad screen by having its aspect ratio changed./fixed; the actual image is giant (way bigger than the iPad resolution). This scaled aspect ratio remains even when zooming in on the image, and causes the image to look stretched.

No matter what I try, I cannot stop the iPad from automatically rescaling my image. I simply want the app to start with my image displayed normally (100% zoom) on the iPad, with the portion that currently fits on the iPad screen being the top-left corner of the image.

**What I've tried to fix it:**

I tried changing the `UIImageView's` content-mode in Interface Builder to "Top-Left". This appeared to work perfectly, but then I realized that the `UIScrollView` would not let you scroll around the image past the initially displayed portion (the top-left). You could zoom-in on the top-left portion and scroll, but never past what was initially shown on the screen.

**Code:**

Here's the code that I'm using to setup the views. `imageScrollView` is the `UIScrollView`, and `imageView` is the `UIImageView`. They are both `IBOutlets`.

```
   // Set the needed attributes of the imageView
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"TestImage.png"]];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    // Set a bunch of the imageScrollView attributes.

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:1];
    [imageScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:10];
    [imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
    [imageScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [imageScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    imageScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imageScrollView.bounces = FALSE;
    imageScrollView.bouncesZoom = FALSE;
```

I also have two `UIGestureRecongizers` to handle tap-zooming, but I do not believe that they are the issue. When I comment them out, nothing changes.

Any help would be *extremely* appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I fixed it!

For anyone else having the same problem, here's how I fixed the code:

**The Cause** of the bug was that Interface Builder was forcing the views to use the `ScaleToFill` `contentMode`. Setting the `ScrollView's` contentMode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` didn't work on its own, since the `imageView` was still being distorted.

**The Fix:**

The following code had to be added at the end of the setup for the `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView` (inside of the `viewDidLoad()` method):

```
    [imageScrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageView sizeToFit];
    [imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
```

**Explanation:**

First, the `UIScrollView's` `contentMode` is set to `AspectFit`, like @Mike suggested. Then, sizeToFit() is called on the `imageView` to override Interface Builder's annoying presets, and to make the image the correct size.

The last line is important. You **must** set the `contentSize` for the ScrollView AFTER you re-size the `imageView`. Otherwise, the `ScrollView` will think that the image is still the size of the iPad display, and therefore won't think that there's anything to scroll. Setting the size of the `ScrollView` **after** resizing the `ImageView` and changing the `ScrollView's` `contentMode` makes the `ScrollView` the actual size of the image.

Hope that helped!

Thanks for the help Mike, it got me on the right track :)

- Alex

Comment: I was experiencing this issue after closing the ChildBrowser where the main view quit scrolling. I used this trick to restore my scroll on the main view.

Comment: Glad (and somewhat sad) to see that after ~2 years the trick still works, and is applicable to other problems. I was using iOS4 when I had this issue, so I figured they'd have fixed it by now...

Comment: @user357086 I'm having the same issue. Can you please explain some more on how you applied this on ChildBrowser?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `imageView` is the content of the scrollview, try changing the `ScrollView's` content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.  Try calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the `imageview`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate the help. 

I tried your suggestion, and unfortunately the program performs in the exact same way! I set the contentMode for the scrollView and called setNeedsDisplay on the imageView at the end of my setup (which is in viewDidLoad() ).

Comment: I don't use IB that much, mostly because of problems like this.  You could try building the views programmatically.  That might flush out the difference/problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling to fix image aspect in landscape mode while using `UICollectionView` while needing image to be fullscreen.

In your `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` do the following:

```
CGFloat newWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width; //if iPad in landscape and fullscreen value is 1024
CGFloat newHeight = image.size.height / image.size.width * newWidth;

cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
cell.imageView.image = image;
cell.scrollView.contentSize = cell.imageView.frame.size;
```

The key thing is to make image view frame the correct size while keeping correct aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me: (Swift)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let imgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "MyImage"))
    imgView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    var size = imgView.frame.size
    size.height = size.height / size.width * scrollView.frame.width
    size.width = scrollView.frame.width
    imgView.frame.size = size
    scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
    scrollView.contentSize = size
}
```